# Converting .FLV files to MP3

Tags: c++, c, audio, mp3, flv

I was wondering if there is a way to convert FLV files to MP3 programly, with an external library or something (and I need a library that I wont be having to copy it's DLL next to the EXE if I'm turning it on, on a computer that doesnt have the library installs - such as OpenCV)..

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) is very good a this, and its open source.

Comment: but when I searched into it, it was looking like a console like library ? I'm not sure I can use it inside a project, and specialy in a place where I have not installed the library ?

Comment: You can link the lib of ffmpeg, no need for the console. You will need to install it. Usually no unix distrib comes with such a tool.

Comment: So there is no tool that I can convert FLV to MP3 without a 3rd part installation?

Comment: check your distribution documentation, but pretty sure that the answer is no.

Comment: So how can I use ffmpeg inside the program? I dont want the user to see the black screen of the convertion... Do you have an example of usage of ffmpeg inside a program to convert flv to mp3 ?

Comment: Yes this is possible and most likely easy to do. I do similar from Qt on windows using QProcess. There are several different ways to do that depending on the framework you use.

Comment: See [Converting .flv to .mp3 server side with FFmpeg](http://audior.ec/blog/converting-flv-to-mp3-server-side-with-ffmpeg/)